# Duplicate Entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE Editor (
UsernameID VARCHAR (30),
EditorName VARCHAR (30),
EMail VARCHAR (30),
DateOfBirth DATE,
BlogTitle VARCHAR(30),
PRIMARY KEY (UsernameID));

INSERT INTO Editor VALUES
('Mdbuzzer','Joshua', 'coker@hotmail.com', '1995-03-15', 'Nearly Bound');

INSERT INTO Editor VALUES
('Kally32','Kally', 'kally@hotmail.com', '1993-10-13', 'Tomorrows War');
SELECT * FROM Editor;



CREATE TABLE Post
(UsernameID VARCHAR (30),
PostID INT,
BlogTitle VARCHAR (30),
PostTitle VARCHAR (30),
CategoryID INT,
TimeofPost VARCHAR (20),
PRIMARY KEY(PostID),
FOREIGN KEY (UsernameID) REFERENCES Editor (UsernameID));

INSERT INTO Post VALUES
('Kally32','1','Tomorrows War', 'Mystery', '4', '12:03pm');

INSERT INTO Post VALUES
('Kally32','1','Tomorrows War', 'Let It Shine','2','10:05pm');

INSERT INTO Post VALUES
('Kally32','1','Tomorrows War','Two Can Play That Game','2', '12:00pm');

INSERT INTO Post VALUES
( 'Mdbuzzer','2','Nearly Bound', 'Goal','3', '10:05pm');

INSERT INTO Post VALUES
( 'Mdbuzzer','2','Nearly Bound','Life After Death','4', '12:03pm');

INSERT INTO Post VALUES
('Mdbuzzer','2', 'Nearly Bound','Times Up','1', '14:06pm');

SELECT * FROM Post;
```

Every time I try and run this script I keep getting an error saying duplicate entry '1' for key 'primary' and I don't really understand how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are inserting multiple rows into the POST table with a PRIMARY KEY of 1. If you are trying to implement a primary key, it must be unique.

So this:

```
INSERT INTO Post VALUES
('Kally32','1','Tomorrows War', 'Mystery', '4', '12:03pm');

INSERT INTO Post VALUES
('Kally32','1','Tomorrows War', 'Let It Shine','2','10:05pm');

INSERT INTO Post VALUES
('Kally32','1','Tomorrows War','Two Can Play That Game','2', '12:00pm');

INSERT INTO Post VALUES
( 'Mdbuzzer','2','Nearly Bound', 'Goal','3', '10:05pm');

INSERT INTO Post VALUES
( 'Mdbuzzer','2','Nearly Bound','Life After Death','4', '12:03pm');

INSERT INTO Post VALUES
('Mdbuzzer','2', 'Nearly Bound','Times Up','1', '14:06pm');
```

Could be changed to something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Post VALUES
('Kally32','1','Tomorrows War', 'Mystery', '4', '12:03pm');

INSERT INTO Post VALUES
('Kally32','2','Tomorrows War', 'Let It Shine','2','10:05pm');

INSERT INTO Post VALUES
('Kally32','3','Tomorrows War','Two Can Play That Game','2', '12:00pm');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make a column a primary key, then every value in the column must be unique. You already have one instance of '1' in the column POST_ID when you add the first tuple:

```
('Kally32','1','Tomorrows War', 'Mystery', '4', '12:03pm');
```

and if you try adding another tuple with the instance of '1' in the column POST_ID, such as:

```
('Kally32','1','Tomorrows War', 'Let It Shine','2','10:05pm');
```

you will get an error.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `PostId` to be the primary key of `POST`.

When you use `insert`, you should always include the columns.  So, these are the first two inserts into the table:

```
INSERT INTO Post(UsernameID, PostID, BlogTitle, PostTitle, CategoryID, TimeofPost)
    VALUES('Kally32','1','Tomorrows War', 'Let It Shine','2','10:05pm');

INSERT INTO Post(UsernameID, PostID, BlogTitle, PostTitle, CategoryID, TimeofPost)
    VALUES('Kally32','1','Tomorrows War','Two Can Play That Game','2', '12:00pm');
```

You are setting `PostId` to the same value, `1`, in both cases.  Hence the error.

I would expect the code to look like:

```
CREATE TABLE Post (
    UsernameID VARCHAR (30),
    PostID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    BlogTitle VARCHAR (30),
    PostTitle VARCHAR (30),
    CategoryID INT,
    TimeofPost VARCHAR (20),
    FOREIGN KEY (UsernameID) REFERENCES Editor (UsernameID)
);

INSERT INTO Post(UsernameID, BlogTitle, PostTitle, CategoryID, TimeofPost)
    VALUES('Kally32', 'Tomorrows War', 'Let It Shine', 2, '10:05pm');
```

Comment: Yes.  This is a very typical approach.